# Why don't electrons simply diffuse back when illuminating a photodiode?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

Assuming you connect the cathode and the anode with a conductor (no sources), why can't the electron-hole pairs created by the photons diffuse back instead of going through the wire?

My reasoning is that the "new" electron (hole) that drifts towards the n (p) doped side will be as if you reduced the charge in the depletion zone, hence I would expect the "diffusion force" to bring back the equilibrium, after all that's how the depletion layer was formed in the first place. But if that were the case, why does a current appear in the external conductor?

Below is a picture of what really happens.

[image]

Comment: What makes you think they don't? The right question is *what fraction* of photoelectrons recombine with their holes without contributing to an external current. It's often surprisingly small.

Comment: Why is the fraction so low? is it because the depletion zone is depleted of majority carriers?

Comment: By what mechanism will the electron and hole recombine?  If the material is high quality, there should be no mid-gap states, so SRH recombination is unlikely. Direct recombination is lower probability, and requires matching momenta of the particles. If the photon is above the bandgap the electron-hole pair will be left with some kinetic energy, so they will move apart and not have matching momenta. Now if you shine a lot of light onto the junction than you can create enough carriers to make it easier to recombine, but that causes other issues to the physics beyond the scope of this comment....

Comment: @Jon_Custer Thanks. I meant the same mechanism that formed the electric field in the first place: an electron in the n-doped side falling into a hole in the p-side (directly), I did not imply that it had to be the same electron excited by the photon. If that could not happen you would end up with a contradiction (suddenly the equilibrium voltage is lower). What I'm trying to understand is why that process is so unlikely to happen compared with a current flowing through the external conductor.